# Getting Export Failed error in Export Layout tool of ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, export, layouts, pdf, jpg

I get the "Export Failed" error message when I run the Export Layout tool of ArcGIS Pro. It happens then I try exporting a JPEG, or a .pdf. When I have layers visible or none visible. In the past, I have been able to, but for now,  I cannot export any layouts. I tried restarting ArcGIS Pro and it still does not work.

I am running ArcGIS Pro 2.9.0

Comment: Have you tried creating a new project and map to add a single layer to, and then added that map in a map frame to a layout, to see if you can export a layout using a simple test case?  If you can’t then I think an uninstall/reinstall might be a wise next step.

Answer (score 1):

The one known issue I am aware of is a crash when exporting with dynamic text elements which have no contents.  There is a fix for this coming in next maintenance update (2.9.1), or you can remove the blank text elements manually from the layout.

Gross failure to export means something else is going wrong.  If it's specific to this map/layout, please share the repro case by packaging a PPKX (share->Project package) and sending it in with your support request.